# Display All Quarters based on Year In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I Need to display all the Quarters from date field.

```
SELECT '2021' AS YOE,DATEPART(Quarter,'2021')AS [Quarter],450 AS Qty
```

Actual Result:

| YOE | Quarter | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 450 |

Expected Result:

| YOE | Quarter | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1 | 450 |
| 2021 | 2 | 0 |
| 2021 | 3 | 0 |
| 2021 | 4 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that will get you results for any given year.
What you need to do is start with a calendar table as the driving row, then `LEFT JOIN` your table to it.

We will use [Itzik Ben-Gan's tally table](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge) for this purpose. We pass through the starting year as `@startingYear`:

```sql
;WITH
  L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
          FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                      (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
  L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
  Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
            FROM L1 ),
  Years AS ( SELECT DATEADD(year, rownum - 1, @startingYear) AS Year FROM Nums)

SELECT
    y.Year AS YOE,
    q.Quarter,
    SUM(t.Value) AS Qty
FROM Years AS y
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4) ) AS q(Quarter)
LEFT JOIN (Table AS t
    -- any other inner or left joins between Table and ON
)
  ON DATEPART(Quarter,t.Date) = q.Quarter AND
        t.Date >= DATETIMEFROMPARTS(@startingYear, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `values()`:

```
SELECT '2021' AS YOE, vv.*
FROM (VALUES (1, 350), (2, 0), (3, 0), (4, 0)) v([Quarter], Qty)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use from Recursive CTE?

Comment: @Thiyagu Yes - why don't you try it and see. But really there is no reason to since you KNOW that you simply need the values of 1 through 4. Why make this more complicated?

Comment: I beginning to smell that the OP hasn't told us the *real* problem here, @SMor .

Answer (score 0):

Considering it seems that this isn't against a table, but you are "creating" the data, use a `VALUES` table construct:

```
SELECT YOE,
       [Quarter],
       Qty
FROM (VALUES(2021,1,450), --Numerical values don't go in quotes.
            (2021,2,0),   --Strings and Numerical values are very different,
            (2021,3,0),   --don't confuse the 2.
            (2021,4,0))V(YOE,[Quarter],Qty)
ORDER BY YOE,
         [Quarter];
```

Comment: Is it possible to use from Recursive CTE?

Comment: Yes, but why use a rCTE at all for 4 rows? But a Tally would be way faster than an rCTE.